# Display Posts by Category in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have some issues that happen with my code for displaying posts by category..
Relation is one to many, post to category.. I can route to choosen category, but posts did not show..

Here's my Post Model:

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoriesPost::class);
    }
```

Category Model:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

And here's my PostController

```
$posts = Post::where('article_status', 'published')->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($slug) {
            return $query->where('category_slug', $slug);
        });

$category = CategoriesPost::where('category_slug', $slug)->first();

return view('pages.article', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'category' => $category,
        ]);
```

I'm so sure my code was right, but why it didn't shows the posts, did anyone notice where's the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than querying for the related `Posts` separately, why not access them via the relationship you have defined in your `Category` model? It will improve performance by reducing the number of calls to your database for a start.

So something like:

```
$category = CategoriesPost::with(['posts'])->where('category_slug', $slug)->first();
```

Then you can just access your `posts` relationship on the `$category` property in your view:

```
$category->posts;
```